# Помогите найти ошибку в коде для задания

Tags: python, list

Задание:
`Определите количество чисел кратных 5 , в промежутке от 100 до 104`

Код:

```py
x=[]
    for I in range(100, 105):
        if I : 5 == 0
            x. append (I)
    print(len(x))
```

Comment: в питоне нет оператора двоеточие

Comment: if I % 5 == 0:  или if not I % 5: В одно строчку print(len([x for x in range(100, 105) if not x % 5]))

Answer (score 1):

```
x=[]
for i in range(100, 105):
    if i % 5 == 0:
        x.append(i)
print(len(x))
```

Подучите синтаксис